# How to make an array automatically change when other array's sequence changes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sequence

There are tow correlative arrays.

How to make an array change when other array's sequence changes with Javascript?

For instance,array1(1,3,2),array2(3,2,1), I need array 2 to become(2,1,3)when I make array 1 in descending order(3,2,1)?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: It cant be done unless you have an event for this. For example, onLoad(), onClick() etc. You can write a function inside the eventlistener function, and inside this function, you may evaluate your first array and rearrange your second array.

Comment: nothing automatic about programming - it's all done in code, of which, you've provided none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want,

Assuming both arrays have same length, so whenever i am changing positions of 2 elements of array, will need to change the positions of elements of other array as well.

```
var array1 = [1,3,2];
var array2 = [3,2,1];
var swapArrayElements = function(index1, index2) {
  var temp1 = array1[index1];
  array1[index1] = array1[index2];
  array1[index2] = temp1;

  var temp2 = array2[index1];
  array2[index1] = array2[index2];
  array2[index2] = temp2;
};

swapArrayElements(0,2); //out: array1[2, 3, 1] & array2[1, 2, 3]
swapArrayElements(0,1); //out: array1[3, 2, 1] & array2[2, 1, 3]
```

Or another approach,

```
const array1 = [1,3,2];
const array2 = [3,2,1];

const swapArrayElements = function (x, y, arr) {
  if (arr.length === 1 || x >= arr.length || y >= arr.length) return arr;
  arr.splice(y, 1, arr.splice(x, 1, arr[y])[0]);
};

const swapArrays = (i1, i2, ...args) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    swapArrayElements(i1, i2, args[i]);
  }
}
swapArrays(0, 2, array1, array2); //out: array1[2, 3, 1] & array2[1, 2, 3]
swapArrays(0, 1, array1, array2); //out: array1[3, 2, 1] & array2[2, 1, 3]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!